# Cannot remove eventListener from inside a function

Tags: javascript

I call a function with an "if / else" statement inside it which adds or removes a listener based on the Boolean value passed as argument.
My problem is I cannot remove the previously added listener by calling the same function
What I'm missing?

```
function listenerTest(handler) {
    if(handler) {
        window.addEventListener("click", clickFn);
    }
    else {
        window.removeEventListener("click", clickFn);
    }

    function clickFn(event) {
        console.log(event)
    }
}        

listenerTest(true);  

window.setTimeout(listenerTest, 5000, false);  
   // call the "listenerTest" function 5 seconds later with "false" argument does NOT remove the listener
```

I've ran multiple tests, interestingly this is working

```
function listenerTest(handler) {
    if(handler) {
        window.addEventListener("click", clickFn);      // listener added
        window.removeEventListener("click", clickFn);   // and removed right after in the same block scope
    }

    function clickFn(event) {
        console.log(event)
    }
}        

listenerTest(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove clickFn and put it outside the scope of listenerTest. Its creating a new instance every time the function is called, because clickFn is hoisted to the top of the listenerTest function.

```
function clickFn(event) {
  console.log(event)
}

function listenerTest(handler) {
    if(handler) {
        window.addEventListener("click", clickFn);
    }
    else {
        window.removeEventListener("click", clickFn);
    }
}        

listenerTest(true);  

window.setTimeout(listenerTest, 5000, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because every time function 'listenerTest' is called, a new memory address is being assigned to function 'clickFn', so when you try to remove it, it is a different function than when you added it to the event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a conditional before listenerTest(true)
checking if the listener exists
    **getComponentListeners** could be useful